# How to test project when 3rd party modules used aren't transpiled

Tags: npm, react-native, mocha.js, babeljs, enzyme

I am trying to use enzyme to test my React Native project, and have followed the set up instructions.

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/react-native.md

```
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
     "test": "mocha --require react-native-mock/mock.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive test/**/*.js"
  },
```

This works fine and my own code is correctly transpiled, but when I include a modules that do not transpile their code (for instance https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), my tests refuse to run as it errors at the import statements in these modules.

How can I make babel transpile these modules or is there another way to get my tests to run?

**Update**

It seems that non transpiled 3rd party modules are fairly common with React Native since React Native itself isn't transpiled.

The solution does seem to be a combination of forcing transpiling, and using react-native-mock.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5392

However I am having further issues with react-native-router-flux due to NavigationExperimental not being mocked.

Related links are:

https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock/issues/23
https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock/issues/22
https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock/pull/34

I will update here if I find a solution.

**Update 2**

I have included my current workaround below in case anyone finds it useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37655424/168012

Comment: You installed `react-native-router-flux` from npm? And it's not ES5?

Comment: @JMM Yes. I just had to double check as I am now pulling directly off a branch, but yes the install from NPM is ES6. A recent PR to change was abandoned so I am looking for an alternative solution https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is as follows (given no current support for NavigationExperimental in ReactNativeMock):

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "mocha --require test/init.js --recursive test/**/*.js"
  },
```

**/test/init.js**

```
require('react-native-mock/mock');

require("babel-register")({
    only: [
        "/node_modules/react-native-tab-navigator/*.js",
        "/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/*.js",
        "/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/*.js",
        "/node_modules/react-native-tabs/*.js",
        "/node_modules/react-native-button/*.js",
        "/node_modules/react-native-swipeout/*.js",
        "/app/**/*",
        "/test/**/*",
    ]
});

import mockery from 'mockery';
mockery.enable();
mockery.registerMock('react-native-router-flux', {Actions:{}});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `--compilers js:babel-core/register` you could try creating your own script that invokes the require hook (and BTW it's better to use `babel-register` package) and use the `only|ignore` option:

```js
// init.js
require("babel-register")({
  only: [
    "/my-app-dir/src/**/*",
    "/my-app-dir/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/**/*",
  ]
});
```

```
mocha --require ./init.js
```

That is in general a really dubious way of publishing a package though. This is assuming the `.babelrc` is published with the package. Even so, since stuff it references are called `devDependencies` it seems you'd need to manually go into its folder and install them.

Comment: Further investigation reveals this seems to be common practice with React Native modules, since React Native itself isn't transpiled.

Answer (score 0):

That's is my testHelper.js to handle react-native- 3th party modules

```
require('babel-polyfill');
require('react-native-mock/mock');

// require('babel-core/register')({
//   ignore: function(packageName) {
//     if (packageName.match(/node_modules/)) {
//       return !(packageName.match(/react-native-vector-icons/)
//         || packageName.match(/react-native-animatable/)
//         || packageName.match(/react-native-router-flux/)
//         || packageName.match(/react-native-tab-navigator/)
//       );
//     }
//     return false;
//   }
// });

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function getBabelRC() {
  var rcpath = path.join(__dirname, '.babelrc');
  var source = fs.readFileSync(rcpath).toString();
  return JSON.parse(source);
}

var config = getBabelRC();

config.ignore = function(filename) {
  if (!(/\/node_modules\//).test(filename)) {
    console.log(filename, 'FALSE');
    return false; // if not in node_modules, we want to compile it
  } else if ((/\/node_modules\/react-native.*\//).test(filename)) {
    // its RN source code, so we want to compile it
    console.log(filename, 'FALSE');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(filename, 'TRUE');
    // it's in node modules and NOT RN source code
    return true;
  }
};

require("babel-register")(config);

global.__DEV__ = true;


// var chai = require('chai');
// var dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai');
// chai.use(dirtyChai);

import chai from 'chai';
import dirtyChai from 'dirty-chai';
// import chaiImmutable from 'chai-immutable';

chai.use(dirtyChai);
//chai.use(chaiImmutable);

import mockery from "mockery";

mockery.enable();
mockery.registerMock('./menu_burger.png', 0);
```

and this is my npm test

```
"test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require testHelper.js **/__test__/*.js",
```